# Auto Block Abusive customer in Einstein ChatBot Salesforce

Tags: einstein-chatbot

can anyone help in auto-blocking customers when they enter abusive language in the chatbot e.g when chatbot asks for the first name, last name, or email Id? Also, we cant use blocking from IP addresses as these IP addresses are not known for some customers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-the-box functionality for this. You can keep a list of keywords in a record somewhere that the Bot can check against, and then end the chat if a customer uses one of them.

Like, incase of bot you can [build a simple rule](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bots_service_setup_dialog_rule.htm&type=5), if value = (swear word) then go to the End chat dialog. It'd be exactly the same in an Omni routing flow if you don't have a Bot.

Related: [Block Sensitive Data in Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.messaging_block_sensitive_data.htm&type=5)